# Why do I need different bounded contexts

Tags: domain-driven-design, bounded-contexts

I've read that the reason to split the application in different bounded contexts is because of the ubiquitous Language and also to split big entities. For example, I can have a Product entity with logic for Support and Sales and I can split the model into two Product models in different bounded contexts - Support and Sales bounded contexts, but I can also just create two different entities SupportProduct and SalesProduct and achieve the same result? So why also do I need different bounded contexts?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Answer (score 2):

Bounded contexts don't really have anything to do with the application or code, they're for problem decomposition and a means of recording the fact that sales domain experts and support domain experts mean different things when they talk about a product entails.

So `SupportProduct` and `SalesProduct` are valid encodings of the fact that "product" exists in two different bounded contexts; you might choose this encoding if you're aiming for a more monolithic implementation in a language which doesn't support modules/packages/namespaces (in a language which does have such support you might have something like `sales.Product` and `support.Product`).

Bounded contexts don't imply anything about code structure, or deployment into different (possibly micro-)services, although that decomposition does suggest some natural seams with which to structure code/deployment.

Comment: Totally agree with @Levi. `SupportProduct` and `SalesProduct` are valid options to start with. Having both `Product` and `Sales` separated in 2 different deployable units, will come handy if 2 different team would be responsible for each Bounded Context. `Product` and `Sales` could then have different life cycles.